# PHP $_REQUEST variables is incorrect

Tags: php, request

I have an URL like this:

```
www.example.com/account?user=1&other=2
```

When I want to parse variables from `$_REQUEST` it return like this:

```
q=account?user=1
```

and
    other=2

Of course I want: `user=1` and `other=2`

So, why do I get the variable `q` rather than the first variable (`user`)?

I tried to use `$_REQUEST['user']` but it does not exists in `$_REQUEST`

And if I use `print_r($_REQUEST)` it return like this:

```
Array ( [q] => /account/?user=1 [other] => 2 )
```

Comment: When you're debugging, `var_dump` will be your best friend. [Go introduce yourself](http://php.net/var_dump) and come back once you've become better acquainted.

Comment: seems `.htaccess` modifying your query parameter. Can you please post your .htaccess if any

Comment: My site is using wordpress and .htaccess is standard of wordpress: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`

Answer (score 1):

```
You can get it via
$_REQUEST['user']
$_REQUEST['other']

OR
$_GET['user']
$_GET['other']
```

Comment: That is problem: $_REQUEST['user'] does not exists and if I use print_r($_REQUEST); the results is Array
(
    [q] => /account/?user=1
    [other] => 2
)

Answer (score 0):

You can get full array by

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

And get value by

```
$_REQUEST['user'];
$_REQUEST['other'];
```

or

```
 $_GET['user'];
 $_GET['other'];
```